# Using Wordpress post via email with 000webhost

Tags: wordpress, email

I'm using Wordpress 3.8 beta 1 running on 000webhost's free servers. I've created an email to post to my blog when I don't want to log in, but I can't seem to get it working.

- Mail Server: mx.000webhost.com
- Login Name: xxxxxxxxxxxxxx@onlinecalc.host56.com
- Password: The correct password.

I sent a test post with the subject of "Testing WP-Email Post" and body of "I'm trying to use WordPress' post via email system." a few days ago, and the post still hasn't apperd on my blog!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using Gmail here. Follow the steps below which have been found on:http://themefuse.com/blog/posting-to-wordpress-via-email-theres-a-safe-way-of-doing-this/

> **Using Gmail**
>
> Yes, Gmail will help us big time here.
>
> Start by creating a new Gmail account with whatever username you wish.
> You can even go with “secretemailformyblogposting@gmail.com” … it
> truly doesn’t matter. What matters is what we’re going to do later on.
>
> Go to your Gmail settings. Then “Forwarding and POP/IMAP” and enable
> the “Enable POP for all mail (even mail that’s already been
> downloaded)” feature. From now on your Gmail is supporting the
> possibility of downloading messages via POP protocol (which WordPress
> uses for email postings).
>
> This next step is the crucial one. What we’re going to do here is
> choose an email address which will be the only one allowed to send
> anything to your new Gmail account, and therefore to post something to
> your blog.
>
> Go to “Filters” and “Create a new filter.” In the “from” field input
> your primary email address and add a hyphen just before it. Example:
> –yourmainemail@domain.com. Then press “Create filter with this
> search.” Tick the “Delete it” checkbox, and press “create filter.”
> That’s it.
>
> From now on every email that hasn’t been sent from your own email
> address will be immediately deleted.

Comment: Thanks, that added nessary security, but my post still don't appear! Is this feature broken in the beta?

Comment: I have just loaded up the beta on my server (cent os and plesk) and tried to achieve what you are and mine is working fine? Why not move your site to say localhost and see if it works there as it may be a hosting problem.